# How do I receive and respond to Apple Events in a Java program?

Tags: java, applescript

I want to have my Java swing application be applescriptable.

I am not trying to just respond to pre-defined events like open, print, etc.

It would be best if the AppleEvents appeared through a Listener interface.

Edit:
A little bit of explanation of my understanding of Apple Events may help demonstrate that I'm not a slacker. :-)
I've written code here that demonstrates how to respond to a lot of the pre-defined events:

https://github.com/joelkevinjones/snippets/blob/e7b10128156bcc213f8c24dbda464ad09a8a1e33/Java/AppleSpecific/AppleLookAndFeelDemo.java

Apple Events are delivered to regular applications using a non-Java interface.  There are no supplied Java methods for obtaining these events, so far as I've been able to discover.  The Apple Event technology includes writing "terminology" files which describe in human readable form what events an application responds to and the four-letter codes for building up Apple Events programatically.  Creating an instance of javax.script.ScriptEngine doesn't do what I want.  It allows a Java program to initiate calling AppleScript, but no means for having AppleScript call a Java program.

To clarify, are there are already written libraries or examples that show how to:

1. Mark or register certain Java methods as being "visible" as AppleScript methods and/or classes as AppleScript classes.
2. Failing a declarative approach, is there a Java method for capturing Apple Events sent to the Java application?  If the event just gets returned as an array of bytes, then the event can be parsed and turned into a Swing event and the reverse process can be used to return results to the application that sent the Apple Event.
3. Or does lots of JNI code need to written?

Comment: Very good decisions so far ..appreciated!!!.

Comment: 1. There is no question in the description above.
2. What have you tried?
You won't get any good answers here if you do not show some effort.

Comment: What did you end up doing Joel?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet, as this is a side project. I'd still like to have an answer though.

Comment: @Joel I'm still interested to find if anything has emerged as a solution. I am currently delivering ***clasew*** (on github) which is a clojure wrapper for calling applescript but being able to respond to events would be sublime!

Comment: I haven't found a way yet, but I really  haven't looked.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the Application and ApplicationAdaptor classes available in the com.apple.eawt package. By implementing the event handlers in the ApplicationAdaptor class, your application can generate and handle basic events such as Print and Open. Information on these two classes is available in J2SE 5.0 Apple Extensions Reference.

Java SE 6 also enables you to invoke AppleScript with the javax.script API. The listing below provides a sample implementation of this functionality.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    String script = "say \"Hello from Java\"";

    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScript");
    engine.eval(script);
}
```

source: http://qery.us/3xr

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However, I've already written the code that handles the standard events.  I"m wanting my Java application to be able to respond to its own set of apple events.  As far as I can tell, I'm going to have to use the Cocoa scripting bridge, create proxy objects that call JNI or JNA to effect changes in my Java objects.